# Displaying the combined data in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

given a table:

```
my_table:
**PERSON**  **AGE**
  person1     20
  person1     20
  person2     30
  person2     30
```

how can i display the data where person = person and age = age, i.e:

```
person1  40
person2  60
```

?

Comment: If you're seriously thinking about storing someone's age then you're seriously nuts

Answer (score 1):

You can group by person name, and sum the age, although it seems a bit odd to do that. If two people say I'm 20, then it doesn't make me 40. :)

```
SELECT   person,
         SUM(age) as age
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY person
```